# Is far cry vengeance a remake of far cry instincts evolution or is it an alternate version of far cry instincts evolution?

Tags: far-cry

So I'm playing through thee far cry series so i was wondering is far cry vengeance a remake of far cry instincts evolution or is it an alternate version of far cry instincts evolution? Because i want to finish every game in order except for far cry instincts predator cause that's a remake of far cry instincts and evolution. So yeah if you know please answer. Bye.

Comment: why was this down voted?

Comment: Probably because you could have easily found this answer yourself with 5 minutes of effort. I don't mean to sound rude, but you're supposed to show that you tried to find the answer to your question before you asked it here.

Comment: i did try to but no answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, Far Cry Vengeance is basically a remake of Instincts Evolution.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Cry#Far_Cry_Vengeance